# Deleted usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib -- computer won't start

Tags: macos

Long version:

I mistakenly deleted `usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib` and now the computer will no longer start (it just stays in startup mode indefinitely). Would the solution be to reinstall the operating system? The computer came with Snow Leopard and have since upgraded to Mountain Lion. If I reinstall the Snow Leopard version (given that's the one I have a disk for) am I in danger of losing anything on the hard drive?

Short version:

I actually have the correct version of `libxml2.2.dylib` saved on the `Desktop`, so if I could get into the computer I may be able to fix the problem.

Comment: If on ML can't yo boot into the recovery partition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still have the Snow Leopard Installation DVD you should be able to solve the issue by booting from DVD and then open Terminal to copy the missing file from your desktop (which will be in `/Volumes/however-your-disk-is-called/Users/Dash/Desktop`) back into the correct location (`/Volumes/however-your-disk-is-called/usr/lib/`).

Comment: doen't that depend on the version of libxml2 being the same on the SL CD and on the users ML - which is a gap of 2-3 years is not certain

Comment: Idea would be to copy the version you had on your desktop

Comment: Oops yes I misread your answer

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the comment, it got me to edit the answer to make it more clear.